# Google maps load additional markers when map is dragged

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've created a Google Map where markers are loaded via Json. I have been doing a lot of research to load additional markers when the map is dragged, but the function onClickCallback does not get fired. Would you please help me?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAQmgDjepa9e-ce16YlwjKBD9gJRfnQUEI&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
       <style type="text/css">
          #map {
            width: 800px;
            height: 600px;
          }

      #latlng-control {
        background: #ffc;
        border: 1px solid #676767;
        font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        padding: 2px 4px;
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">


   $(function() { 

var map;
var infoWindow;
var bounds;
var markers = new Array();
var markers = [];


var lat = 47.2081;
var lon = 10.14175;
var zoom = 11;



   function initialize() {

var mapOptions = { 
center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon), 
zoom: zoom, 
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    }


};

  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);



  // Define an info window on the map.
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
   onClickCallback(map);

    }); 


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function() {
    var bounds = this.getBounds();
    onClickCallback(map);

});



}






function onClickCallback(map) {

var bounds = map.getBounds();   

 // clearOverlays();


    $.getJSON( 'http://skiweather.eu/gmap4/markers/index.php', {
        swLat: bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), swLon: bounds.getSouthWest().lng(), 
        neLat: bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), neLon: bounds.getNorthEast().lng()}, function(data) { 
        $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {


        // Define Marker properties
        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(marker.smallimg,
        // This marker is 129 pixels wide by 42 pixels tall.
            new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 18,42.
            new google.maps.Point(18, 42)
        );


            $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 'id' : marker.id,
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),
                'icon' : image,             
                'bounds': true 
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': '<h2>' + marker.loc + '</h2><img src="' + marker.smallimg + '" class="my-map-marker" />'
                 }, this);
            });
        });
    });

    return false;
}   



 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);   




    });



</script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>

        <div id="loading">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you like to see current version: http://skiweather.eu/gmap4/

Comment: This is not the simplest answer, so I add it here as food for thought. I used a combination of custom overlay and prototyped the MyOverlay.draw() function. The ajax call happens in the draw function. Then within dragend event you call MyOverlay.draw(). See code example of the overlay relationship here http://nickjohnson.com/b/google-maps-v3-how-to-quickly-add-many-markers

Comment: Thank you Nick, I made the change to the script according to your specs http://skiweather.eu/gmap5/ Can you please have a look (not plotting yet)

Comment: I see some issues that can be troubleshooted via a console. You have the data from ajax you need to add your own custom markers and dialogs. Google loads markers and dialogs quite inefficiently. I have developed a jQuery plugin that was built to speed up marker and dialog loading. It handles the ajax bit too. I haven't released it publicly via github yet. Contact me here http://nickjohnson.com/contact for the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you changed it from `'dragend'` to `'idle'` it would serve two purposes. It would run the search for thumbnails after a zoom event and a pan event.

bounds are updated for both pan and zoom?

[See here !Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/MK2f2/3/)

Comment: yes, your example works. But with my onClickCallback function it just fires two ajax calls with same bounds. Draging does not result in call with new bounds

Comment: @mark I updated the fiddle to what you were trying to do I think. the `getBounds` call will get the visible area after a pan or zoom ... I thought thats what you were looking for?